# using kendo ui grid on backbone,require,underscore and kendo

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs, kendo-ui

How can i load or instantiate a kendo ui grid using Kendo UI grid , backbone.js , underscore.js and require.js Is it possible?

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'text!templates/cart/cartlist.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, CartListTemplate){

var mainHomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#cartContainer"),
render: function(){
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: ["ItemDescription", "Qty", "Price", { command: "destroy" }],
  });
  this.el.html(CartListTemplate);
}
});
 return new mainHomeView;
});
```

And this

```
CartListView.render();
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general reference, I wrote a blog post about using jQuery plugins with Backbone, and mention KendoUI several times as my preferred control suite:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/20/using-jquery-plugins-and-ui-controls-with-backbone/

To answer your question specifically, you have an error in your render method.

When you call `$("#grid").kendoGrid(...);`, you are telling jQuery to look for the `#grid` element in teh DOM of the page, but that doesn't exist yet because it's coming from your `CartListTemplate`. You need to use `this.$` to find the `#grid` within your view's HTML, after you set the `el.html` of the view.

```
render: function(){
  this.$el.html(CartListTemplate);
  this.$("#grid").kendoGrid(...);
}
```